# python selenium unable to click on a tag

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on this button shown below named “Segment Metrix 2.0 Consumer Target Profile report“

[image]

and I found corresponding HTML as shown below.

[image]

I tried to write code as below:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Segment Metrix 2.0 Consumer Target Profile report ')]")
print (elem)
```

it gives me:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="daf65f4e5ed0485027d04eed8db8aca7", element="0.8079987809618281-1")>]
```

But I can't click on it by adding `elem[0].click()`, it throws me an "element not visible" error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait until element become visible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Segment Metrix 2.0 Consumer Target Profile report"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried but I get a timeoutexception: 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: '

Comment: Did you click on "Segment dec" before clicking "Segment Metrix 2.0 Consumer Target Profile report"?

Comment: You are right! I didn't click on segment dec.  Just clicked it and it works! Thx  ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the element **has to be visible**. It means that even if it's in html, it's not enough, it has to been visible from the browser. Try to click on the dropdown first in order to see its elements and only than click on one of the elements. Also, after clicking on the dropdown, don't forget to wait until your element will be seen, either explicitly or implicitly.

Do you sure you need to click on it? If it is just an object with an url, exact the url and use `driver.get(url)`

Comment: Very good explanation! I clicked on the dropdown list and it works! Thx. And yes I have to click on it cos the url remains the same all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the element to be visible

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Segment Metrix 2.0 Consumer Target Profile report ')]")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(elem[0]))
elem[0].click()
```